# Average the data in sql table

Tags: sql, average

I need your help in following case.

i have table ChartData

in that table i have large number of records as per below

```
PK,ProjectID,MAchineId,Powervalue,PowerData
1     1         1         20.5     2011-07-05 12:00:00    
2     1         1         21.5     2011-07-05 12:01:00
3     1         1         22.5     2011-07-05 12:02:00
4     1         1         23.5     2011-07-05 12:03:00
5     1         1         24.5     2011-07-05 12:04:00

6     1         1         25.5     2011-07-05 12:05:00    
7     1         1         26.5     2011-07-05 12:06:00
8     1         1         27.5     2011-07-05 12:07:00
9     1         1         26.5     2011-07-05 12:08:00
10     1        1         28.5     2011-07-05 12:09:00
```

Output

```
PK,ProjectID,MAchineId,Powervalue(Avg value of power),PowerData

1     1         1           20.5            2011-07-05 12:00:00    
6     1         1           25.5            2011-07-05 12:05:00
```

any help would be appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: Why group in rows of 5? What about gaps in the PK? is it grouped on the datetime value? What about missing intervals if so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to aggregate every five tuples? If so, maybe something like this will help:

`SELECT PK, ProjectID, MachineID, AVG(Powervalue), PowerData FROM table GROUP BY (PK-1)/5`

although I don't really know if you can do that with GROUP BY

@gbn: I would like to answer to your comment directly, but I think I lack the privilege. Can you explain why this will fail on all but MySql?

Comment: And if there are gaps in the PK? This will fail on every platform except MySQL because of incorrect aggregate syntax too. And on MySQL it won't give output that OP mentioned...

Answer (score 2):

```
Select * from ChartData where PK=1 or PK=6
```

You are not doing any averages as far as i know

Answer (score 0):

You just want the average powervalue?

```
SELECT PK,ProjectID,MachineID, AVG(PowerValue), PowerData FROM ChartData
```

If you'd for example want the average powervalue per machine, this would become the query:

```
SELECT PK,ProjectID,MachineID, AVG(PowerValue), PowerData FROM ChartData GROUP BY MachineID
```

Comment: This will fail on every platform except MySQL because of incorrect aggregate syntax. And on MySQL it won't give output that OP mentioned.

Comment: It's kinda difficult to understand the OP's question. Its not like he's asking something.

Comment: @TJHeuvel  I want like this but for every five minutes.

Comment: Of what type is PowerData? DateTime, Timestamp or worse varchar?

Comment: @TJHeuvel Powerdata is datetime

Comment: @Hitesh Patel: what about gaps in the intervals? Readings every 1 minute *always*?

Answer (score 0):

Select every 5th record (T-SQL).

```
select
        ch.*
    from
        (select
                row_number() over (order by pk asc) as r,
                pk
            from
                chartdata
        ) as r
        inner join chartdata as ch
            on r.pk = c.pl
    where
        (r.r-1)%5 = 0
;
```

Without further clarification on what you want this is the best answer I can give.